# Does an element of an infinite Power Set always have a minimum?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider $P(\Bbb Z )$. An exercise asks me if $\forall X \in P(\Bbb Z )$, $\exists \min X$.

I think this is not possible because, in this part of $\Bbb Z$ there is no maximum (same can be done for minimum):

$\exists X \in P(\Bbb Z): \forall x \in \Bbb Z, x > 0$

Am I wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain your notation? In particular, what is $P(\mathbb{Z})$ here and the meaning of $minX$?

Comment: P($\Bbb Z$) is the power set of Z and $min X$ is the minimum of the set X in $\Bbb P(\Bbb Z)$

Comment: Well of course $\mathbb{Z} \in P(\mathbb{Z})$, and there is no minimum element in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Any $X \in P(\Bbb Z)$ has no minimum element in $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand you meaning of minimum, but of course many sets have a minimum element. The set $\{1\}$ for example. The question you posed asked if every set has a minimum, not if every set does not have a minimum.